# Magento on google cloud not working after RESET

Tags: magento, google-cloud-platform, magento2

I deployed Magento 2.2 on google cloud using the standard deployment from google marketplace. Everything was working fine initially. When i visit the external IP address I would see the site. After a hard reset of the VM, the site went down. Not sure what is going on.
Compute engine external address should be https://104.154.249.237